# Gitbook-cli install error TypeError: cb.apply is not a function inside graceful-fs

Tags: node.js, npm, gitbook

When executing any `gitbook` command in the terminal, the following error is thrown:

```
/home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/gitbook-cli/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:287
      if (cb) cb.apply(this, arguments)
                 ^
TypeError: cb.apply is not a function
    at /home/travis/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3/lib/node_modules/gitbook-cli/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:287:18
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:169:5)
```

NOTE: This does not happen in node version v12.18.2 and is still happening in version v14.6.0

The `gitbook-cli` seems to not be working right now, failing because of their outdated `graceful-fs` dependency.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I was able to set my node version to v12.18.2 and get the gitbook-cli to work. This is a "good enough" solution for me, until the following issue is addressed: https://github.com/GitbookIO/gitbook-cli/issues/110

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The issue was originally a problem inside `graceful-fs` but they solved it in [this commit](https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs/commit/168bdb8f0bb3174e8499d4bc5878deead4172c39) I believe.

The problem is that GitBook is still using outdated dependencies that pull in versions of graceful-fs without the fix.

The solution I found was to update `graceful-fs` inside gitbook like this:

If you've installed gitbook globally by doing `npm install -g gitbook-cli` then your path in macOS should be something like `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gitbook-cli/node_modules/npm/node_modules`. Your path may differ depending on your OS or installation location.

Run this:

```
cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gitbook-cli/node_modules/npm/node_modules/
npm install graceful-fs@latest --save
```

Then try installing GitBook. It should have fixed the installing problem.

Comment: that's really useful answer.

Comment: this is very useful in my macbook

Comment: For those not using macOs find your global npm installation path using `npm root -g` .

Comment: This solution worked like a charm for me. For those who have installed node using nvm, the path may be different. I was able to find the location of gitbook via `which gitbook`

Comment: This seems to not work anymore with the latest version of `graceful-fs`. Gitbook just exits silently after any command. Version `graceful-fs@4.2.4` seems to work.

Comment: Sorry, but this ecosystem is so broken. I still see `TypeError: cb.apply is not a function` with `graceful-fs@4.2.4`

Comment: @KirillTaran solution worked for me!
This also worked for me (install another version):
`npm install gitbook-cli@2.1.2 --global`

Comment: The latest module for graceful-fs didn't work for me. The below did:

`cd /opt/homebrew/lib/node_modules/gitbook-cli/node_modules/npm/node_modules; npm install graceful-fs@4.2.0 --save`

Answer (score 20):

TL;DR

Why not switch to [honkit](https://github.com/honkit/honkit)(Fork of GitBook)?

---

The "why" for switching:

I knew this is not the answer to the question, but I would like to mention that the repository of gitbook has been deprecated 3 years ago, this makes it a bad choice for usage and especially security.

So I searched for the alternatives, and I found [mdBook](https://github.com/rust-lang/mdBook) and [honkit](https://github.com/honkit/honkit), turned out that [honkit](https://github.com/honkit/honkit) has good compatibility with gitbook, maybe switch to [honkit](https://github.com/honkit/honkit) is a better choice instead of fixing a 3 years old software with some hacking.

Comment: makes total sense, that's actually what I've done, I've switched to docusaurus. Although this could have been a comment instead of a full answer.

Comment: I've liked to read this struct as a viable alternative to the gitbook problem, trying honkit out

Comment: if you love book making, another choice is [dartbook](https://github.com/lindeer/dartbook),  completely compatible with gitbook project but implemented in Dart, and run more fast than gitbook and honkit

Answer (score 12):

The last solution was great , but when I use `npm install graceful-fs@latest --save`  in the right place and  then rerun `gitbook build`  , I got the following error:

```
_stream_readable.js:545
  switch (state.pipesCount) {
               ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipesCount' of undefined
    at module.exports.Readable.pipe (_stream_readable.js:545:16)
    at module.exports.ZipArchiveOutputStream._smartStream (/node_modules/compress-commons/lib/archivers/zip/zip-archive-output-stream.js:184:11)
    at module.exports.ZipArchiveOutputStream._appendStream (/node_modules/compress-commons/lib/archivers/zip/zip-archive-output-stream.js:96:20)
    at module.exports.ArchiveOutputStream.entry (/node_modules/compress-commons/lib/archivers/archive-output-stream.js:88:10)
    at module.exports.ZipStream.entry (/node_modules/zip-stream/index.js:138:49)
    at Zip.append (/node_modules/archiver/lib/plugins/zip.js:53:15)
    at Archiver._moduleAppend (/node_modules/archiver/lib/core.js:172:16)
    at Archiver._onQueueTask (/node_modules/archiver/lib/core.js:370:8)
    at /node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3879:9
```

And ... guess what , when I `change the version of graceful-fs to 4.2.0` , it all worked ...

Comment: I got a different error (`TypeError: Cannot set property 'readableListening' of undefined` for `internal/streams/readable.js:864    state.readableListening = this.listenerCount('readable') > 0;`) when installing the `katex` plugin but this solution helped me fix it nevertheless.

Comment: @a_guest were you able to solve this error?

Comment: @alireza Yes, despite starting from a different error, this answer helped to resolve it. All I did was downgrading `graceful-fs` to `4.2.0`.

Answer (score 7):

Just replace the crashing file `polyfills.js` with this one:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs/168bdb8f0bb3174e8499d4bc5878deead4172c39/polyfills.js

This works like a charm in Node.js v16.13.0.

Answer (score 3):

@Chalist 's Solution also was not working for me. So, I did this :

1. `npm uninstall gitbook-cli -g`
2. `nvm install 10`
3. `nvm use 10`
4. `npm install gitbook-cli -g`

Now all gitbook commands like `gitbook serve` will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Full instructions for WSL2

**Install nvm**
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash
close WSL bash shell and re-open
nvm install --lts

**check versions and install**
node --version
npm --version

**install gitbook-cli**
npm install -g gitbook-cli

**Any gitbook command gives error**
gitbook build
TypeError: Cannot set property 'readableListening' of undefined for internal/streams/readable.js:864    state.readableListening = this.listenerCount('readable') > 0;

cd /home/<USER_NAME>/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.1/lib/node_modules/gitbook-cli/node_modules/npm/node_modules/
npm install graceful-fs@4.2.0 --save

Then cd to your git document folder
gitbook install
gitbook serve

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
npm install graceful-fs@latest --save
```

Then re-run:

```
npm install -g gitbook-cli
```

UPDATE =====
Another option would be to use NVM and install node v12.8.2.

Use this https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm.

Answer (score 1):

for those who are very busy and have no time to debug:

1. install an older version of gitbook:

```
 npm install gitbook-cli@2.1.2 --global
```

2. modify this file: `vim ~/.gitbook/versions/3.2.3/lib/output/website/copyPluginAssets.js`, Replace all `confirm: true` to

```
confirm: false
```

3. `gitbook serve`

then everything goes well.

My Env:

- ubuntu 20.04 LTS ( windows WSL)
- node 16

Answer (score 1):

I changed the Node version to `12` with nvm and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

My working solution on macOS Sonoma 14.2.1 (23C71)

- brew install nvm (follow the shell modification instructions)
- nvm install 12
- nvm use 12
- npm install graceful-fs@4.2.0 -g
- npm install gitbook-cli@2.1.2 -g

Testing

- gitbook init
- gitbook serve

This constellation is working now nicely